# Swift: Cast generic type into same generic type but with a subclass of associated type

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics, inheritance

Consider these classes:

```
struct OrderedSet<T: Hashable> {}

class Exercise: Hashable {}

class StrengthExercise: Exercise {}

class CardioExercise: Exercise {}
```

I'd like to do the following:

```
var displayedExercises = OrderedSet<Exercise>() {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
var cardioExercises = OrderedSet<CardioExercise>()
var strengthExercises = OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>()


@IBAction func segmentControlChanged(segmentControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:     self.displayedExercises = self.strengthExercises
    case 1:     self.displayedExercises = self.cardioExercises
    default:    break
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>' to type 'OrderedSet<Exercise>
```

I don't quite get this, since `StrengthExercise` is a subclass of `Exercise` and will have everything that `OrderedSet<Exercise>` expects.

**The question(s)**

- Why is this error necessary?
- How to I write something that achieves the functionality I'm going for?

**Radar filed** 
[rdar://23608799](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4993657711099904)

**Blog post on covariance and contravariance** 
https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html

Comment: Is this a case where having a protocol (Exercisable? lol) is better than a class hierarchy? Or perhaps categories/extensions?

Comment: Fun aside: for the didSet: function of displayed exercise would you wrap the call to reload the tableview in a dispatch)async to the main queue or rely on documenting the interface to say you must set the value on the main queue?

Comment: @Cocoadelica of course! Lovely idea! ❤️ it! Adding a `dispatch_async()` to the main queue is also a good idea. I'd prefer that over documenting because then it's only written once and the new developer approaching it doesn't have to learn anything extra. Perhaps you should offer this as an answer? If no one offers an answer that also explains why the error is necessary, I could accept yours :)

Comment: @Cocoadelica I strongly suspect `displayedExercises` is used by the table view data source callbacks, so if anything is setting that variable from anything other than the main thread the `reloadData()` call being on the wrong thread will be the least of your troubles—you will be concurrently modifying a collection! So either you assume `displayedExercises` is only ever set on the main thread and `dispatch_async` is unnecessary or if it is called from multiple threads, additional synchronisation all over the shop is needed.

Comment: @NicholasH. Good call. In that circumstance you're quite right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid this is not currently possible as of Swift 2.1. Only the following conversions are supported

- Built in collections types are covariant on their element type.
- Conversions between function types are supported, exhibiting covariance in function result types and contravariance in function parameter types. (Cf. [Xcode 7.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-SW12))

As Objective-C's generics support type variance, and given the progress made on function type conversions in Swift 2.1, I believe there is reason to believe type variance support will be added to Swift in the future. In the mean time, remember to file a radar, like [jlieske has](https://openradar.appspot.com/17226586).

In the mean time you will have to copy the collection or use one of the builtin collection types.

**Update since Swift become open source:**
I believe the *Complete generics* section of [Swift 3.0 Dev Roadmap](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution#development-major-version--swift-30) indicates type variance will be addressed in 3.0. While type variance is not specifically called out, special cased exceptions in the standard library (which includes type variance) are.

Comment: I wonder if conforming to `CollectionType` would give this functionality? Worth trying?

Comment: @kylejm it would appear you are right about `CollectionType` enabling the special cased behaviour of the type system.

Comment: @kylejm rolled back answer to original version based on discussion on @user3441734's answer indicating that it is not sufficient to inherit from `CollectionType` after all.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas! Will file a radar in a moment :)

Answer (score 2):

As the `OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>` is of that specific type it cannot be assigned to the more general `OrderedSet<Exercise>`. Think about what would happen if you tried to append a Cardio exercise to that OrderedSet after assigning it.

The answer might be to modify append the contents of the strength exercises set to the exercise set rather than assign the whole typed set.

Comment: I still don't understand why assigning a more specific type to a more general type is a problem here. The OrderedSet is a struct, so it's passed by value? Therefore, appending something to `displayedExercises` would not affect `strengthExercises` if you assigned `strengthExercises` to it before hand. What's more, you could not append a `CardioExercise` to `displayedExercises`, since it's of type `OrderedSet<Exercise>`.

Comment: I think I get it now! In writing that comment to you, I realised the problem! What if I were to append an `Exercise` to `displayedExercises` and it actually contained `StrengthExercises`! Which is why you can't assign an `OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>` to `displayedExercises`! Got it! Thank you!

Comment: On second thoughts, I still don't see why this would be a problem, since `displayedExercises` would have it's own copy of `OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>` because `OrderedSet` is a struct (pass by value). So appending an `Exercise` to it would not be a problem, since it would append said `Exercise` to `strengthExercises` as well?

Comment: OrderedSet<StrengthExercise> IS the type, it is not just an ordered set that happens to be holding Strength Exercises. You could init a new OrderedSet based on its contents and type that as OrderedSet<Exercise> but that would absolutely be a new value of a new type.

Comment: What about covariance. Does Swift not support covariance for non-builtin types? (Sorry don't use Swift day-to-day.) It would be very disappointing if not. Even Objective-C's lightweight generics support type variance, cf. `@interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType>`.

Comment: Thanks @JosephLord, I'll add that to the pile of solutions, which already includes Cocoadelica's protocol comment.

Comment: @NicholasH I haven't seen anything on covariant yet, but I'll have a look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @kylejm see my updated answer, i hope it helps you to understand what's going in your code

Comment: I exactly know what's going on my code. believe me, or not :-) in you code var displayedExercises = OrderedSet<Exercise>() var cardioExercises = OrderedSet<CardioExercise>() var strengthExercises = OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>(), in my example Base = Exercise ...  the resulting error message is clear enough. you have to understand that my class MyClass also conforms to Hashable but that only means Equatable with hashValue. the rest of MyClass has nothing with your Exercise. both your classes has one super class Exercise. so use T:Exercise as your generic type ...thats all

Comment: @kylejm I am close to my computer now. I checked your playground and updated my answer to reflect you needs. please, see my updated answer, check the OrderedSet signature (the same as yours) and check the result on the end of my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
class Base {}
class A: Base {}
class B: Base {}

var arrBase: Array<Base> = []

var arrA: Array<A> = []
arrA.append(A())

var arrB: Array<B> = []
arrB.append(B())

arrBase = arrA   // no error
arrBase = arrB   // no error
```

... your trouble seems to be somewhere else in your code. can you show us your generic struct  OrderedSet implementation ?? it seems like you are trying to do something like

```
class Base {}
class A: Base {}

let base = Base()
let a = A()

struct S<T:Base> {
    var t: T
}
var s = S(t: base)
let sa = S(t: a)
//s = sa  // error: cannot assign value of type 'S<A>' to type 'S<Base>'
let sb = S(t: a as Base)
s = sb
```

... this works

```
protocol P {
    func whoAmI()->Void
}
class Base:P {
    func whoAmI() {
        print("I am Base")
    }
}
class A: Base {
    override func whoAmI() {
        print("I am A")
    }
}

let base = Base()
let a = A()

struct S<T: Base> {
    var t: Base
}
var s = S(t: base)
let sa = S(t: a)
s = sa

s.t.whoAmI() // I am A
```

.... guys, build-in type or not

```
import Foundation
// Int and Double conforms to Hashable protocol
var a: Set<Int> = []
var b: Set<Double> = []
a = b   // IMPOSSIBLE eventhough Set<T:Hashable> is build-in Swift type
```

... how to deal with OrderedSet

```
import Foundation

class Exercise: Hashable {
    var name: String = ""
    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.hashValue
    }
}
func ==(lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
class StrengthExercise: Exercise {}
class CardioExercise: Exercise {}
var displayedExercises = Set<Exercise>()
let strengthExercises = Set<StrengthExercise>()
let cardioExercises = Set<CardioExercise>()
displayedExercises = strengthExercises

// OK, the question is how to implement OrderedSet<T:Hashable>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  OrderedSet.swift
//  Weebly
//
//  Created by James Richard on 10/22/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Weebly. All rights reserved.
//
//  Slightly modified by user3441734 on 11/18/15
//  
//  original code OrderedSet is available under the MIT license


/// An ordered, unique collection of objects.
public struct OrderedSet<T: Hashable> {
    private var contents = [T: Index]() // Needs to have a value of Index instead of Void for fast removals
    private var sequencedContents = Array<UnsafeMutablePointer<T>>()

    /**
     Inititalizes an empty ordered set.

     :return: An empty ordered set.
     */
    public init() { }

    /**
     Initializes a new ordered set with the order and contents
     of sequence.

     If an object appears more than once in the sequence it will only appear
     once in the ordered set, at the position of its first occurance.

     :param: sequence The sequence to initialize the ordered set with.
     :return: An initialized ordered set with the contents of sequence.
     */
    public init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(sequence: S) {
        // FIXME: For some reason, Swift gives the error "Cannot convert the expression's type 'S' to type 'S'" with a regular for-in, so this is a hack to fix that.
        var gen = sequence.generate()
        while let object: T = gen.next() {
            if contents[object] == nil {
                contents[object] = contents.count

                let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
                pointer.initialize(object)
                sequencedContents.append(pointer)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     Replace, remove, or retrieve an object in the ordered set.

     When setting an index to nil the object will be removed. If
     it is not the last object in the set, all subsequent objects
     will be shifted down one position.

     When setting an index to another object, the existing object
     at that index will be removed. If you attempt to set an index
     that does not currently have an object, this is a no-op.

     :param:     index   The index to retrieve or set.
     :return:   On get operations, the object at the specified index, or nil
     if no object exists at that index.
     */
    public subscript(index: Index) -> T {
        get {
            return sequencedContents[index].memory
        }

        set {
            contents[sequencedContents[index].memory] = nil
            contents[newValue] = index
            sequencedContents[index].memory = newValue
        }
    }


    /**
     Locate the index of an object in the ordered set.

     It is preferable to use this method over the global find() for performance reasons.

     :param:     object      The object to find the index for.
     :return:    The index of the object, or nil if the object is not in the ordered set.
     */
    public func indexOfObject(object: T) -> Index? {
        if let index = contents[object] {
            return index
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// The number of objects contained in the ordered set.
    public var count: Int {
        return contents.count
    }

    /// Whether the ordered set has any objects or not.
    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return count == 0
    }

    /**
     Tests if the ordered set contains an object or not.

     :param:     object  The object to search for.
     :return:    true if the object exists in the ordered set, otherwise false.
     */
    public func contains(object: T) -> Bool {
        return contents[object] != nil
    }

    /**
     Appends an object to the end of the ordered set.

     :param:     object  The object to be appended.
     */
    mutating public func append(object: T) {
        if contents[object] != nil {
            return
        }

        contents[object] = contents.count

        let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
        pointer.initialize(object)
        sequencedContents.append(pointer)
    }

    /**
     Appends a sequence of objects to the end of the ordered set.

     :param:     objects  The objects to be appended.
     */
    mutating public func appendObjects<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(objects: S) {
        var gen = objects.generate()
        while let object: T = gen.next() {
            append(object)
        }
    }

    /**
     Removes an object from the ordered set.

     If the object exists in the ordered set, it will be removed.
     If it is not the last object in the ordered set, subsequent
     objects will be shifted down one position.

     :param:     object  The object to be removed.
     */
    mutating public func remove(object: T) {
        if let index = contents[object] {
            contents[object] = nil
            sequencedContents[index].dealloc(1)
            sequencedContents.removeAtIndex(index)

            for (object, i) in contents {
                if i < index {
                    continue
                }

                contents[object] = i - 1
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     Removes the given objects from the ordered set.

     :param:     objects     The objects to be removed.
     */
    mutating public func removeObjects<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(objects: S) {
        var gen = objects.generate()
        while let object: T = gen.next() {
            remove(object)
        }
    }

    /**
     Removes an object at a given index.

     This method will cause a fatal error if you attempt to move an object to an index that is out of bounds.

     :param:     index       The index of the object to be removed.
     */
    mutating public func removeObjectAtIndex(index: Index) {
        if index < 0 || index >= count {
            fatalError("Attempting to remove an object at an index that does not exist")
        }

        remove(sequencedContents[index].memory)
    }

    /**
     Removes all objects in the ordered set.
     */
    mutating public func removeAllObjects() {
        contents.removeAll()
        sequencedContents.removeAll()
    }

    /**
     Return an OrderedSet containing the results of calling
     `transform(x)` on each element `x` of `self`

     :param:     transform   A closure that is called for each element in the ordered set.
     The result of the closure is appended to the new ordered set.
     :result:     An ordered set containing the result of `transform(x)` on each element.
     */
    public func map<U: Hashable>(transform: (T) -> U) -> OrderedSet<U> {
        var result = OrderedSet<U>()

        for object in self {
            result.append(transform(object))
        }

        return result
    }

    /// The first object in the ordered set, or nil if it is empty.
    public var first: T? {
        return count > 0 ? self[0] : nil
    }

    /// The last object in the ordered set, or nil if it is empty.
    public var last: T? {
        return count > 0 ? self[count - 1] : nil
    }

    /**
     Swaps two objects contained within the ordered set.

     Both objects must exist within the set, or the swap will not occur.

     :param:     first   The first object to be swapped.
     :param:     second  The second object to be swapped.
     */
    mutating public func swapObject(first: T, withObject second: T) {
        if let firstPosition = contents[first] {
            if let secondPosition = contents[second] {
                contents[first] = secondPosition
                contents[second] = firstPosition

                sequencedContents[firstPosition].memory = second
                sequencedContents[secondPosition].memory = first
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     Tests if the ordered set contains any objects within a sequence.

     :param:     sequence    The sequence to look for the intersection in.
     :return:    Returns true if the sequence and set contain any equal objects, otherwise false.
     */
    public func intersectsSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(sequence: S) -> Bool {
        var gen = sequence.generate()
        while let object: T = gen.next() {
            if contains(object) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    /**
     Tests if a the ordered set is a subset of another sequence.

     :param:     sequence    The sequence to check.
     :return:    true if the sequence contains all objects contained in the receiver, otherwise false.
     */
    public func isSubsetOfSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(sequence: S) -> Bool {
        for (object, _) in contents {
            if !sequence.contains(object) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    /**
     Moves an object to a different index, shifting all objects in between the movement.

     This method is a no-op if the object doesn't exist in the set or the index is the
     same that the object is currently at.

     This method will cause a fatal error if you attempt to move an object to an index that is out of bounds.

     :param:     object  The object to be moved
     :param:     index   The index that the object should be moved to.
     */
    mutating public func moveObject(object: T, toIndex index: Index) {
        if index < 0 || index >= count {
            fatalError("Attempting to move an object at an index that does not exist")
        }

        if let position = contents[object] {
            // Return if the client attempted to move to the current index
            if position == index {
                return
            }

            let adjustment = position < index ? -1 : 1
            let range = index < position ? index..<position : position..<index
            for (object, i) in contents {
                // Skip items not within the range of movement
                if i < range.startIndex || i > range.endIndex || i == position {
                    continue
                }

                let originalIndex = contents[object]!
                let newIndex = i + adjustment

                let firstObject = sequencedContents[originalIndex].memory
                let secondObject = sequencedContents[newIndex].memory

                sequencedContents[originalIndex].memory = secondObject
                sequencedContents[newIndex].memory = firstObject

                contents[object] = newIndex
            }

            contents[object] = index
        }
    }

    /**
     Moves an object from one index to a different index, shifting all objects in between the movement.

     This method is a no-op if the index is the same that the object is currently at.

     This method will cause a fatal error if you attempt to move an object fro man index that is out of bounds
     or to an index that is out of bounds.

     :param:     index   The index of the object to be moved.
     :param:     toIndex   The index that the object should be moved to.
     */
    mutating public func moveObjectAtIndex(index: Index, toIndex: Index) {
        if ((index < 0 || index >= count) || (toIndex < 0 || toIndex >= count)) {
            fatalError("Attempting to move an object at or to an index that does not exist")
        }

        moveObject(self[index], toIndex: toIndex)
    }

    /**
     Inserts an object at a given index, shifting all objects above it up one.

     This method will cause a fatal error if you attempt to insert the object out of bounds.

     If the object already exists in the OrderedSet, this operation is a no-op.

     :param:     object      The object to be inserted.
     :param:     atIndex     The index to be inserted at.
     */
    mutating public func insertObject(object: T, atIndex index: Index) {
        if index > count || index < 0 {
            fatalError("Attempting to insert an object at an index that does not exist")
        }

        if contents[object] != nil {
            return
        }

        // Append our object, then swap them until its at the end.
        append(object)

        for i in Range(start: index, end: count-1) {
            swapObject(self[i], withObject: self[i+1])
        }
    }

    /**
     Inserts objects at a given index, shifting all objects above it up one.

     This method will cause a fatal error if you attempt to insert the objects out of bounds.

     If an object in objects already exists in the OrderedSet it will not be added. Objects that occur twice
     in the sequence will only be added once.

     :param:     objects      The objects to be inserted.
     :param:     atIndex      The index to be inserted at.
     */
    mutating public func insertObjects<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(objects: S, atIndex index: Index) {
        if index > count || index < 0 {
            fatalError("Attempting to insert an object at an index that does not exist")
        }

        var addedObjectCount = 0
        // FIXME: For some reason, Swift gives the error "Cannot convert the expression's type 'S' to type 'S'" with a regular for-in, so this is a hack to fix that.
        var gen = objects.generate()

        // This loop will make use of our sequncedContents array to update the contents dictionary's
        // values. During this loop there will be duplicate values in the dictionary.
        while let object: T = gen.next() {
            if contents[object] == nil {
                let seqIdx = index + addedObjectCount
                let element = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
                element.initialize(object)
                sequencedContents.insert(element, atIndex: seqIdx)
                contents[object] = seqIdx
                addedObjectCount++
            }
        }

        // Now we'll remove duplicates and update the shifted objects position in the contents
        // dictionary.
        for i in index + addedObjectCount..<count {
            contents[sequencedContents[i].memory] = i
        }
    }
}

extension OrderedSet: MutableCollectionType {
    public typealias Index = Int
    public typealias _Element = T
    public typealias Generator = OrderedSetGenerator<T>

    public func generate() -> Generator {
        return OrderedSetGenerator(set: self)
    }

    public var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        return count
    }
}

public struct OrderedSetGenerator<T: Hashable>: GeneratorType {
    public typealias Element = T
    private var generator: IndexingGenerator<Array<UnsafeMutablePointer<T>>>

    public init(set: OrderedSet<T>) {
        generator = set.sequencedContents.generate()
    }

    mutating public func next() -> Element? {
        return generator.next()?.memory
    }
}



public func +<T: Hashable, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T> (lhs: OrderedSet<T>, rhs: S) -> OrderedSet<T> {
    var joinedSet = lhs
    joinedSet.appendObjects(rhs)

    return joinedSet
}

public func +=<T: Hashable, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T> (inout lhs: OrderedSet<T>, rhs: S) {
    lhs.appendObjects(rhs)
}

public func -<T: Hashable, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T> (lhs: OrderedSet<T>, rhs: S) -> OrderedSet<T> {
    var purgedSet = lhs
    purgedSet.removeObjects(rhs)

    return purgedSet
}

public func -=<T: Hashable, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T> (inout lhs: OrderedSet<T>, rhs: S) {
    lhs.removeObjects(rhs)
}

extension OrderedSet: Equatable { }

public func ==<T: Hashable> (lhs: OrderedSet<T>, rhs: OrderedSet<T>) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count {
        return false
    }

    for object in lhs {
        if lhs.contents[object] != rhs.contents[object] {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// finaly what do you want

var displayedExercises1 = OrderedSet<Exercise>()
let strengthExercises1 = OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>()
let cardioExercises1 = OrderedSet<CardioExercise>()
displayedExercises = strengthExercises
```

Comment: The problem is not in @kylejm's code, the trouble is that it appears his OrderedSet is invariant. I suspect because Swift doesn't support type variance on non-builtin types. If so that would explain why Array works, it must be special cased somehow to be covariant.

Comment: I don't think we need to see anything about his OrderedSet. It is clearly supposed to be a generic collection. The fact that the type system throws a hissy with empty implementation eliminates his implementation as a factor. Your proposal works around the issue by letting the type inference make `s` and `sa` both `S<Base>` which does not provide a suitable answer to @kylejm's question as `sa` is not actually `S<A>`. Try adding `:S<A>` after `let sa` to see the problem, namely it would appear *Swift generics are invariant*  (except for the special cased builtin types like Array)

Comment: @NicholasH. is it clearly supposed to be a generic collection? his signature is struct of generic type conforming to protocol ...

Comment: @user3441734 like Nicholas says, you're using type inference to achieve this, which doesn't match my code in the question. If you were to set the last declaration of struct `S` to take associations with types conforming to protocol `P` instead of classes of `Base`, which would match `OrderedSet<T: Hashable>`, you'll get an inference error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`. I've made a [playground](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tzn632u73g9se5b/AACaj7si-e2Tv-qIDabrUuJpa?dl=0) to illustrate. It also contains the code in my question.

Comment: What is your OrderedSet ? In your question is is struct. Is it correct, or isn't it?

Comment: Will check your playground when close to computer

Comment: @kylejm so your question is "how should i design generic ordered set in swift?"

Comment: @user3441734 OrderedSet is just a struct, but it doesn't really matter what it is. It will be more clear when you have a chance to look at my playground. All that matters is that it's a struct, associated with a type which conforms to a protocol. In my playground, this is all I declare. There is no implementation to OrderedSet, yet the error still occurs. No, this is not my question. My question is mainly the first bullet point of the two in my question written above. The second bullet merely asks for suggestions of ways to get rid of the error, since I can't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: ordered set is struct, but not just a generic struct with type conforming to Hashable. in case i need ordered collection of values in my set, i am using set.flatMap{ $0 }.sort(). don't ask Swift to do what you want to do. a better approach is use Swift in its natural way.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, @kylejm but as I see it you are trying to implement a generic, covariant collection, just like ones of the built-in ones? Unfortunately this is not possible as of Swift 2.1.

Comment: @user3441734 converting the set to an array and sorting it is potentially much more expensive than a by index lookup in an ordered set, O(n log(n)) in lieu of O(1) potentially.

Comment: @NicholasH. yes, it is a serious problem especially in this context, how to fill a tableview ...

Comment: @NicholasH. please, see my updated answer, which exactly fulfill requirements of kylejms question ...

Comment: @user3441734 thanks for this! I'll give it a go when I'm st my computer in a few moments. It seems my suspicion (see my comment on Nicholas' answer) of conforming `OrderedSet` to `CollectionType`, in this case `MutableCollectionType`, enables the functionally I'm looking for.

Comment: @kylejm i didn't check the original code to much. i slightly modified it just to be able to compile it. i would like to demonstrate, how it is possible to define you own OrderedSet. still my recommendation is the same. use at first Swift's build-in functionality. define new type in case, there is no other change. if i were you, i am going to use Set and sort() function on it. set.sort() return an ordered collection (an array)

Comment: @user3441734 live and learn. I didn't realise that the special cased covariant behaviour was inherited by classes conforming to `CollectionType`.

Comment: @NicholasH. the question is, if it is really good idea ... i am very sceptic about this approach, even though it works.  i hope now you understand, why i asked OP how his OrderedSet is implemented. creating your own generic container can cause many new problems and undesirable behaviors

Comment: @user3441734 your solution still doesn't work I'm afraid. You made a typo on the last line, which is actually referencing the two `Set`s declared at the top of the code snippet. [Here's a playground](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07i6u5o89btkcry/AACKp3YihYwk50tj476I4Rvwa?dl=0) to illustrate. You still get the error I've stated in the question.

Comment: @user3441734 I don't understand why you're sceptic about this approach. People can make their own collections, it's up to them to implement them properly. The actual topic of this question, is why can't we declare the displayedSet as `OrderedSet<Exercise>`, and then set it to an `OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>`, like you've done with a `Set`, and like you could do with an `Array`. It doesn't matter if OrderedSet is a collection or not, it's about being able to set a generic type's value to an instance that's associated with a more specialised type than it was originally declared.

Comment: @kylejm did you check my example correctly? see the very last lines there ..var displayedExercises1 = OrderedSet<Exercise>() 
let strengthExercises1 = OrderedSet<StrengthExercise>() 
let cardioExercises1 = OrderedSet<CardioExercise>() 
displayedExercises = strengthExercises // WORKS!!!

Comment: @kylejm yes i see it now :-)

Comment: @NicholasH. i did one big mistake there !!!! in the last line i worked with Set, not with OrderedSet ... :-) it seems i am to tired ...

Comment: @user3441734 I was happy that to have thought you had solved it! Haha! Thanks for all your help/work with this! :) It seems that Nicholas' answer is correct. Although he needs to re-correct the part about confirming to `CollectionType`, as this clearly doesn't work. It seems that the functionality we're discussing only works for built-in types, as he originally said. Do you agree?

Comment: yes. maybe, i go back in few days. if i find something useful, i will inform you, guys ... at least now we know what we are talking about