# Swift Generic Class can't assign to subclass

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3

I have the class A:

```
class A<T: MyTypeClass>
{
}
```

and the class B

```
class B<T: MyTypeClassSubclass>: A<T>
{
}
```

Lets say that `MyTypeClassSubclass` extends `MyTypeClass`

Swift doesn't let me to do something like:

```
var variable: A<MyTypeClass> = B<MyTypeClassSubclass>()
```

if i write something like:

```
var variable: A<MyTypeClass> = B<MyTypeClassSubclass>() as! A<MyTypeClass>
```

The compiler give's only a warning and the app crashes at runtime.

I tried with type erase but it's doesn't work because, in my case, it's starts with the class A witch is already generic.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: This [Swift: Cast generic type into same generic type but with a subclass of associated type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752968/swift-cast-generic-type-into-same-generic-type-but-with-a-subclass-of-associate) may help

Comment: See especially the posted blog article. https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html. The short answer is that making this covariant is potentially possible (in languages other than Swift, such as Scala), but is a complex language feature to do correctly with type safety, and Swift doesn't have it. You can't do this. Mixing subclasses with non-trivial generics will very often get you into a corner. Generally you should redesign around protocols or type erasers rather than subclassing to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither supertypes nor subtypes are allowed in Swift when dealing with Generic types. The types must be identical when using generics in the context of subclasses.