# Swift generic class, inheritance and covariance

Tags: ios, swift, generics, covariance

I'm faced with the problem of using generic class and inheritance.

Brief description of the problem:

I have a base class called `BookPageDataSource` and two inherited classes (`ReadingBookPageDataSource` and `StarsBookPageDataSource`) with different implementations.

Also, I have a generic class `BookPageViewController` that contains the generic parameter of this data source and two inherited classes (`ReadingBookPageViewController` and `StarsBookPageViewController`) from this class.

I need to write a method the return parameter of which is `BookPageViewController<DataSource>`.

```
// Data Sources

class BookPageDataSource { }

class ReadingBookPageDataSource: BookPageDataSource { }

class StarsBookPageDataSource: BookPageDataSource { }

// Controllers

class BookPageViewController<DataSource: BookPageDataSource>: UIViewController {
    let dataSource: DataSource

    init(dataSource: DataSource) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
}

final class ReadingBookPageViewController: BookPageViewController<ReadingBookPageDataSource> { }

final class StarsBookPageViewController: BookPageViewController<StarsBookPageDataSource> { }

// Communication

class Pager {
    func currentPageController<DataSource>(at index: Int) -> BookPageViewController<DataSource> {
        // for example

        if index == 0 {
            // How to remove the cast from the line below?
            return readingPageController() as! BookPageViewController<DataSource>
        }

        return starsPageController() as! BookPageViewController<DataSource>
    }

    private func readingPageController() -> ReadingBookPageViewController {
        return ReadingBookPageViewController(dataSource: ReadingBookPageDataSource())
    }

    private func starsPageController() -> StarsBookPageViewController {
        return StarsBookPageViewController(dataSource: StarsBookPageDataSource())
    }
}
```

The method `currentPageController` always crashes, because the DataSource is always equals to `BookPageDataSource`, not to `ReadingBookPageDataSource` or `StarsBookPageDataSource`.

Comment: Maybe you need type erasure.

Comment: Do you really need `BookPageDataSource` to be a class? Have you considered the case where it is just a protocol? This way you will just have dependancy injection in the VC init method. What is more you will not need the VC generic where clause.

Comment: @dvp.petrov The `ReadingBookPageDataSource` and `StarsBookPageDataSource` have a lot of the same methods, so I wrote these methods on the base `BookPageDataSource`. If I change the `BookPageDataSource` to the protocol, I will need to add the extensions to the protocol all stored variables should be created with the `objc_associated_objects` methods. This is bad I think...

Comment: I'd agree with dvp.petrov but also you could use `associatedtype` in your ViewController which could be a dataSource

Comment: @Sweeper Could you explain how to do this in the current example?

Comment: @inokey But if you create a protocol with associated type and add inheritance, the result will be the same.

Comment: A `BookPageViewController<DateSource>` is not a  `BookPageViewController<ReadingBookPageDataSource>`.
The compiler tells you incase you don‘t force-cast with `as!`. Printing the error when you remove the `!` may be helpful. Try to constrain the type parameter in `currentPageController()` too to `DataSource: BookPageDataSource`.

Comment: @Purpose This doesn't work. Could you provide a code please?

Comment: @AndrewKochulab `Cannot convert value of type 'BookPageViewController<ReadingBookPageDataSource>' to specified type 'BookPageViewController<BookPageDataSource>' ` is the error you are interested in. It says that you can't treat a `Generic<Child>` as a `Generic<Parent>`. If you want an explanation best look for this, its more specific than `crashes on forced cast` so you may dig up more why now.

Comment: @Purpose Yes, but there is no techniques/code to fix this problem?

Comment: @AndrewKochulab no idea but I‘ve not looked hard at it.

Comment: As @Purpose said, a  `obj<Subclass>` cannot be assigned to an `obj<Base>` (nor vice versa), becasue the tipes are invariant. You could also check this question, which is quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752968/swift-cast-generic-type-into-same-generic-type-but-with-a-subclass-of-associate

Comment: @AndrewKochulab could you show some of you code in the `BookPageDataSource`. What you are saying about the protocol extension is right, and yet there might not be the need for `objc_associated_objects`. e.g. https://medium.com/@valv0/computed-properties-and-extensions-a-pure-swift-approach-64733768112c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Conceptual Discussion

Your concept for the architecture is flawed and this is leading to your issue.

---

### Simple Generics Example

Here's a very simple example of a generic function, which just returns the value you give it:

```
func echo <T> (_ value: T) -> T { return value }
```

Because this function is generic, there is ambiguity about the type that it uses. What is `T`? Swift is a type-safe language, which means that ultimately there is not allowed to be any ambiguity about type whatsoever. So why is this echo function allowed? The answer is that when I actually use this function somewhere, the ambiguity about the type will be removed. For example:

```
let myValue = echo(7)      // myValue is now of type Int and has the value 7
```

In the act of *using* this generic function I have removed the ambiguity by passing it an `Int`, and therefore the compiler has no uncertainty about the types involved.

---

### Your Function

```
func currentPageController <DataSource> (at index: Int) -> BookPageViewController<DataSource>
```

Your function only uses the generic parameter `DataSource` in the return type, not in the input - how is the compiler supposed figure out what `DataSource` is?<sup>*</sup> I assume this is how you imagined using your function:

```
let pager = Pager()
let controller = pager.currentPageController(at: 0)
```

But now, what is the type of `controller`? What can you expect to be able to do with it? It seems that you're hoping that `controller` will take on the correct type based on the *value* that you pass in (`0`), but this is not how it works. The generic parameter is determined based on the *type* of the input, not the *value* of the input. You're hoping that passing in `0` will yield one return type, while `1` will yield a different one - but this is forbidden in Swift. Both `0` and `1` are of type `Int`, and the *type* is all that can matter.

As is usually the case with Swift, it is not the language/compiler that is preventing you from doing something. It is that you haven't yet logically formulated what is even is that you want, and the compiler is just informing you of the fact that what you've written so far doesn't make sense.

---

## Solutions

Let's move on to giving you a solution though.

---

### UIViewController Functionality

Presumably there is something that you wanted to use `controller` for. What is it that you actually need? If you just want to push it onto a navigation controller then you don't need it to be a `BookPageViewController`. You only need it to be a `UIViewController` to use that functionality, so your function can become this:

```
func currentPageController (at index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    if index == 0 {
        return readingPageController()
    }
    return starsPageController()
}
```

And you can push the controller that it returns onto a navigation stack.

---

### Custom Functionality (Non-Generic)

If, however, you need to use some functionality which is specific to a `BookPageViewController` then it depends what it is you want to do. If there is a method on `BookPageViewController` like this:

```
func doSomething (input: Int) -> String
```

which doesn't make use of the generic parameter `DataSource` then probably you'll want to separate out that function into its own protocol/superclass which isn't generic. For example:

```
protocol DoesSomething {
  func doSomething (input: Int) -> String
}
```

and then have `BookPageViewController` conform to it:

```
extension BookPageViewController: DoesSomething {
  func doSomething (input: Int) -> String {
    return "put your implementation here"
  }
}
```

Now the return type of your function can be this non-generic protocol:

```
func currentPageController (at index: Int) -> DoesSomething {
    if index == 0 {
        return readingPageController()
    }
    return starsPageController()
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
let pager = Pager()
let controller = pager.currentPageController(at: 0)
let retrievedValue = controller.doSomething(input: 7)
```

Of course, if the return type is no longer a `UIViewController` of any sort then you probably want to consider renaming the function and the related variables.

---

### Custom Functionality (Generic)

The other option is that you can't separate out the functionality you need into a non-generic protocol/superclass because this functionality makes use of the generic parameter `DataSource`. A basic example is:

```
extension BookPageViewController {
  func setDataSource (_ newValue: DataSource) {
    self.dataSource = newValue
  }
}
```

So in this case you really do need the return type of your function to be `BookPageViewController<DataSource>`. What do you do? Well, if what you really want is to use the `setDataSource(_:)` method defined above then you must have a `DataSource` object that you plan to pass in as an argument, right? If this is the case then we're making progress. Previously, you only had some `Int` value which you were passing into your function and the problem was that you couldn't specify your generic return type with that. But if you already have a `BookPageDataSource` value then it is at least logically possible for you to use this to specialize your 
function.

What you say you want, however, is to just use an `Int` to get the controller at that index, regardless of what the `DataSource` type is. But if you don't care what the `DataSource` is of the returned `BookPageViewController` then how can you expect to set its `DataSource` to something else using the `setDataSource(_:)` method?

You see, the problem solves itself. The only reason you would need the return type of your function to be generic is if the subsequent functionality you need to make use of uses that generic type, but if this is the case then the controller you get back can't have just any old `DataSource` (you just wanted whichever one corresponds to the index you provide) - you need it to have exactly the type of `DataSource` which you plan to pass in when you use it, otherwise you're giving it the wrong type.

So the ultimate answer to your question is that, in the way that you were conceiving of it, there is no possible use for the function you were trying to construct. What's very cool about the way Swift is architected is that the compiler is actually able to figure out that logical flaw and prevent you from building your code until you've re-conceptualized it.

---

Footnote:

<sup>*</sup> It is possible to have a generic function which only uses the generic parameter in the return type and not in the input, but this won't help you here.